# simple javascript button onclick function if/else not work

Tags: javascript

I'm a javaScript beginner, 
I'm writing a simple code that Calculate BMI.
Two textbox to input your height and weight, and press the button "calculate" will calculate the formula. The if/else will get the result and say your body figure. Finally will alert the calculate number and the figure! I was wondering why my function can't work, and how can write the correct function to alert both result. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form name="form" id="form">
         BMI_Calculator
         <br>
         Please enter your height(m)
         <input type="numbers" name="height" id="height">
         <br>
         Please enter your weight(kg)
         <input type="numbers" name="weight" id="weight">
     </form>
     <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="add();"></button>
```

and this is the function. Here is my thought, When the caculate is done, put the result ('z') into compare() and execute if/else. If my concept is wrong please tell me. Thank you!

```
function add() {
    var z,s;
    var x=parseFloat(document.getElementById('height').value);

    var y=parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').value);
    s=x*x;
    z=y/s;
    compare(z);
}

function compare() { 
    if(z <= 18) {
        alert("too thin!");
    } else if( z <= 18 && z < 24 ){
        alert("standard!");
    } else {
        alert("too fat!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing any error in console?

Comment: `else(condition)` is not valid syntax (and your logic is flawed too) - `var z,s,;` is also a syntax error ...

Comment: `if (z <=18) ... else if (z <= 24) ... else` is all you need

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks your comments, I have revised my if/else syntax error, but I still not understand why var z,s is syntax error? I just want to use simple variable to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not accept `z` as a parameter in the `compare` function. Also one of your statements is in the wrong syntax. You can write your conditions like this

```js
function add() {
    var z,s;
    var x=parseFloat(document.getElementById('height').value);
    var y=parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').value);
    s=x*x;
    z=y/s;
    compare(z);
}
    
function compare(z) { 
//               ^
    if (z <= 18) {
        alert("too thin!");
    } else if (z < 24) {
        alert("standard!");
    } else {
        alert("too fat!");
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form">
    BMI_Calculator
    <br>
    Please enter your height(m)
    <input type="numbers" name="height" id="height">
    <br>
    Please enter your weight(kg)
    <input type="numbers" name="weight" id="weight">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="add();">
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have tried, but it still can't alert. I have press the button but nothing comes out.

Comment: @Ally See the example

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the value to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function compare has to accept the argument passed

```
function compare(z) { 
    if(z<=18){
        alert("too thin!");
    }else if(z<=18&&z<24){
        alert("standard!");
    }else if(z>=24){
        alert("too fat!");
    }

}
```